# Python/Pygame: How do you take output from a function and use it as input for another?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am making a game with the same idea as Dance Dance Revolution or more so Guitar Hero. Push the corresponding keys on your keyboard that appear on screen. I have made the function to get the output for the keys but now I need to take the output and place it as the input of another function. I assume that this requires the syntax, 'return' just not sure how to go about doing it. This is my current code regarding.

```
def randArrow():

    randArrow = ['left', 'right', 'down', 'up']

    for direction in 'randArrow':
        print(random.choice(randArrow))

    return randArrow
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of taking the output of a function and putting in another:

```
def get_value():
   return 5

def print_value(x):
   print(x)

temporary_variable = get_value()

print_value(temporary_variable)
```

or better:

```
def get_value():
   return 5

def print_value(x):
   print(x)

print_value(get_value())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had a function `printFirstArrow` that took a `list` as an argument, you could pass the output in as `printFirstArrow( randArrow() )`.
ex:

```
def printFirstArrow( arrows ):
    print arrows[0]

printFirstArrow( randArrow() ) // 'left'
```